# Vue 2.x authentication links not hiding until page refresh

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to Vue and created a basic authentication application.

AuthService.js

```
module.exports = {
    isLoggedIn: function() {

        if (localStorage.getItem("authUser") != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    Logout: function() {
        localStorage.removeItem("authUser");
    },


}
```

App.vue

```
<template>

  <div id="app" >
    <top-progress ref="topProgress"></top-progress>
     <div class="nav is-light is-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">


        <span class="nav-toggle" v-on:click="toggleNav" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </span>

        <div class="nav-right nav-menu" v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }">

          <router-link v-ripple to="/" class="nav-item r-item"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</router-link>
          <router-link  v-ripple to="faq" class="nav-item r-item"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Features</router-link>
          <router-link v-ripple  to="dashboard" class="nav-item r-item"><i class="fa fa-dashcube"></i>Dashboard</router-link>
          <router-link v-ripple to="faq" class="nav-item r-item"><i class="fa fa-quora"></i>Faq</router-link>
          <a class="nav-item r-item" v-if="LoggedIn"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" @click.prevent="Logout"></i>Logout</a>
          <div class="nav-item" v-if="!LoggedIn">
            <p class="control">
            <router-link to="login" class="button is-primary is-outlined">
            <span class="icon">
                   <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                </span>
             <span>  Join Now</span>
               </router-link>

            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <br>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <footer class="footer is-secondary">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
          <div class="column">
            <p>And this right here is a spiffy footer, where you can put stuff.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column has-text-right">
            <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </footer>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import {isLoggedIn,Logout} from "./service"

import miniToastr from 'mini-toastr'
import topProgress from 'vue-top-progress'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components:{topProgress},
  data:function(){
    return {
      isActive:false,
      LoggedIn:false,

    }
  },
  created(){

    this.LoggedIn=isLoggedIn();
  },
  mounted(){
     miniToastr.init()
     this.$refs.topProgress.start()
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.topProgress.done()
    }, 2000)
  },
  methods:{

     Logout:function(){
        Logout();
        this.$router.push("login");
    },

  }
}
</script>
<style lang="sass">
   ..//
</style>
```

After successful login, I am using `this.$router.push("home")` to navigate to home component but the Login/Logout button not hiding/showing until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is the `created:` hook is only called when `App.vue` is first created. Since this component holders the `router-view` it is always there as you move around the app — it's never destroyed, so it never needs to be created again. As a result your `this.LoggedIn` is only updated when you first load the app (or as you discovered, hit refresh).

You need to find a different way to update `this.LoggedIn.` One obvious possibility it to set it in the logih/logout methods.

```
Logout:function(){
    Logout();
    this.LoggedIn = isLoggedIn(); // or simply this.LoggedIn = false
    this.$router.push("login");
},
```

It looks like users will login in a different component, so you will need to send an event from the child component to `App.vue` and trigger a method on `App.vue` to set `this.LoggedIn` when users login.

There are probably other possibilities that will come to mind now that you see why it isn't working.